# Windows-1251 против UTF-8

Tags: кодировка, php, mysql

Создаю сайты, используя свой разработанный где-то в 2007 году движок на PHP, который с тех пор прошел всевозможные модификации и улучшения. Кодировка осталась прежняя - windows-1251. Стоит ли переходить на UTF-8? Почти все российские и зарубежные сайты используют кодировку UTF-8.

В чем преимущество кодировки UTF-8 перед windows-1251, и есть ли оно вообще, это преимущество?

И еще вопрос, подскажите, пожалуйста, как грамотно перейти на UTF-8, включая БД MySQL?

Comment: Преимущество в том, что UTF-8 работает со всеми языками и символами

Comment: Ну тогда последний вопрос про переход остается в силе.

Comment: UTF8 также позволит вам хранить на вашей странице текст в разных кодировках и на разных языках, который будет корректно отображаться.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Сделайте полный дамп БД, включая структуру таблиц, в старой кодировке.
- Перекодируйте все страницы сайта и копию дампа в UTF-8.
- Смените кодировку БД по-умолчанию на UTF-8, сравнение на `utf8_general_ci`. Удалите все таблицы.
- Залейте дамп в UTF-8, указав кодировку.
- Разумеется, смените кодировку на utf-8 в заголовках всех страниц сайта.

Про преимущества юникода уже сказал [[@mountpoint](/users/13008/mountpoint)](/users/13008/mountpoint).

Comment: >> Перекодируйте все страницы сайта и копию дампа в UTF-8
А есть ли возможность перекодировать все файлы сразу? Программа какая-нибудь.. JetBrains PhpStorm такое может делать? Ну или PHP Expert Editor. Если да, то как?

Comment: И еще вопрос. Является ли кодировка windows-1251 признаком низкопробной верстки?

Comment: вестка и кодировка в которой сохранен файл как бы немного разные вещи -)

Comment: @MyNameIs, это признак того, что кодер юзает Windows, не более) Добавил ссылку на текстовый редактор, с функцией массового перекодирования, в ответ.

Comment: Тот вопрос был именно про верстку). Ну или про разметку. <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">

Comment: @Risto, спасибо)